Strange behavior of printf when converting a pointer to a double
I was trying to demonstrate what happens if you forget to dereference a pointer by printing a pointer to double double *pd with printf("%f", pd) (instead of using *pd).
I was expecting this to produce a random double value (the double representation of the bit pattern of the address in the pointer).
I was suprised to find that whatever double value I print before that affects the value printed when "forgetting" to dereference the pointer.
Here is the program:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    double d = 123.456, *pd = &d;

    printf("%f ", *pd); // first print
    printf("%f\n", pd);

    return 0;
}

I was suprised to get results like this:

123.456000 123.456000

Now, if I comment the first print, I get this:

0.000000

In fact, whatever double value I print in the first print, gets printed as the double interpretation of the bit pattern of the pointer... for example, this code:
    printf("%f ", 555.555);
    printf("%f\n", pd);

Produced this:

555.555000 555.555000

It looks like this is somehow connected to old left-over values on the stack, but since a pointer is 8 bytes, and a double is also 8 bytes, I don't understand why this is happening.
I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 with gcc version 11.4.0, compiling with:
$ gcc -O0 example.c -o example

Any idea what is going on?

pd has type double *, hence %f is not an appropriate format specifier.  You have undefined behaviour.  Try enabling error checking with -Werror -Wall.

idea: pointers and double/float params are stored in different registers. And the second printf() don't overwrite the floating point register. Anyway, use -Wall to get warnings.

@traveh, "I was expecting this to produce a  ..." --> it is undefined behavior (UB).  Your expectations are at best a curiosity.

In general, C is not amenable to experimentation of the form "I was trying to demonstrate what happens if you ".  There are lots of things that a C compiler will accept that produce undefined behavior when you run the program. Whatever actually does happen in such cases tells you very little other than what actually happened that time. To avoid this, learn the language's rules thoroughly and follow them, and check documentation as needed and conform to it.

This is a common behavior on systems that pass floating-point arguments in separate registers from integer and pointer arguments.
Typically, the specification for how routines pass arguments to other routines (which is part of a document called an application binary interface) says that the first integer/pointer argument is passed in some general register R4 (for illustration; the names and numbers vary in different platforms), the second integer/pointer argument is passed in R5, and so on, and the first floating-point argument is passed in F0, the second is passed in F1, and so on. (Once the designated registers are used up, further arguments are passed on the stack.)
When printf("%f ", *pd); is executed, the address for "%f " is loaded into the appropriate register (R4 in this example), the double for *pd is loaded into its register (F0), and printf is called.
When printf("%f\n", pd); is executed, the address for "%f\n" is loaded into R4. Then, since pd is a pointer, it is loaded into the next register for integer/pointer arguments, R5. The F0 register is left untouched. Then printf is called. printf sees the %f, so it expects a double argument and gets it from F0. Since that register still has the previous double value, that is what is printed.
This is fragile. printf might use the registers while it is formatting numbers to be printed, so it might not leave the previous value in F0. Optimization by the compiler might change various things around the printf statements so that the value is not left in F0 after the first printf call and before the second. The platform you are on might pass arguments differently than this example. But, when you see this behavior, that is what is likely happening.

It might be worth pointing out that using %f to print a pointer is completely undefined behavior, so you're lucky even to get repeatable results.

@MarkRansom: It suffices that the answer states the behavior is fragile. I do not like to feed into the fetishization of undefined behavior that is too prevalent on Stack Overflow, and it is not true that getting repeatable results is “lucky.” When and whether it manifests is primarily a consequence of largely deterministic factors that software engineers should understand and should not attribute to random or mystic forces.

Compiling with different builds and optimization settings may however break everything and when you end up with indeterminate values read from the stack or a register, they are in fact quite random and mysterious. As anyone who've booted a microcontroller from power on reset and peeked at the RAM can attest: then there's just no sensible way of explaining how the random gibberish in RAM ended up that way. ->

Sure, there's a physics/electrical explanation regarding voltage discharge of cells, residue voltage charge in capacitors on the PCB, voltage regulator rising times, CPU reset characteristics, brown-out detect characteristics etc etc. And cosmic microwave backround radiation even. But to analyze all of that is way out of scope for a programmer or even for an electrical engineer.

@Lundin: Understanding how compilers work is not out of scope.  Understanding how linking works is not out of scope. Understanding application binary interfaces is not out of scope.  Understanding processor registers is not out of scope. Closing your eyes and choosing to remain ignorant would be malpractice. Fostering ignorance is malpractice.

I'm not saying that any of it is out of scope and I kind of agree with you regarding the UB paranoia. Just saying that the results of actual computer hardware aren't necessarily easy to explain and indeterminate RAM values could be both random and mysterious. Less so on a PC perhaps, when the OS launched the process. But still no guarantees that the memory cells were touched by any form of software from the point of power up until your program accessed them.

Don't get me wrong, I love your description of the mechanics behind the observed behavior and believe it's likely 100% correct - this time.  But there have been enough problems caused by UB that I think paranoia is a justified attitude.  Vigilance is the only way to avoid it.
